# journald memory usage on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, systemd, memory-usage, journald

I have an AWS EC2 instance running a CentOS 7.7.1908 (systemd 219) with a server application.
The server logs quite a lot of information to the system logs (using syslog).

I have recently enabled persistent storage of the system logs using [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159221/168741).
**Since then**, the memory consumption of systemd-journald is constantly growing.

After a full day, `systemd-journald` ends up using more than 250M of RAM.

I did a quick test to confirm that the journald RAM usage is actually growing.

**Test :**

- Get the `systemd-journald` memory usage
- Log a bunch of data to the system journal using `logger`
- Get the `systemd-journald` memory usage
- Flush the in-memory logs (if any) to /var/log/journal using `journalctl --flush`
- Restart the `systemd-journald` service
- Get the `systemd-journald` memory usage

**The results :**

```
# ps aux | grep journald | grep -v grep
root     23963  0.0  0.1  61320  2500 ?        Ss   15:03   0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
# for i in {0..7000}; do logger -t TEST -p err `python -c 'print "A"*1000'`; done;
# ps aux | grep journald | grep -v grep
root     23963  0.1  0.2  69512 11964 ?        Ss   15:08   0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
# journalctl --flush
# ps aux | grep journald | grep -v grep
root     23963  0.1  0.2  69512 11964 ?        Ss   15:08   0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
# systemctl restart systemd-journald
# ps aux | grep journald | grep -v grep
root     24237  0.0  0.1  55416  2492 ?        Ss   15:08   0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
```

The memory usage goes from 2,5M to almost 12M after logging rougly 7M of data.
Restarting the daemon brings the memory usage back to ~2.5M.

**My interpretation :**

- `systemd-journald` memory usage is proportional to the amount of data it has processed.
- The parameter `RuntimeMaxUse` does not limit this memory usage.
- Restarting `systemd-journald` clears a buffer, that I can not configure the size of.
- There is no configurable limit to the amount of memory `systemd-journald` may use.
- The memory use is not due to logs waiting to be flushed to the disk.

**My journald.conf :**

```
[Journal]
#Storage=auto # /var/log/journal is created and used, so this is equivalent to 'Persistent'
SyncIntervalSec=1m
RateLimitInterval=0
RateLimitBurst=0
SystemMaxUse=4G
RuntimeMaxUse=1M
```

How can I solve this "leak" without restarting the service every day?